# Dont know what type of class I have after doing a <dynamic_cast>

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

I have this structure:

```
class IIterator : public ICollectible{};
class A: public ICollectible{};
class b: public A{};
class c: public A{};
class d: public A{};
```

When I do something like this

```
IIterator* it = colection->getIterator();
whatType* db = dynamic_cast<whatType*>(it->hasCurrent());
```

colection is  list with elements of type `A` (it could have objects of type `b`, `c` or `d`)
`hasCurrent()` gives me something type ICollectible, so I have to do

dynamic cast so I can work 
with `b`, `c` or `d`, but how do I know which one it is?

Comment: What is the point to mix your type if you need to know what is their true type ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: And I would keep 3 differents list of something of class A?

Answer (score 2):

The point of dynamic_cast is that it tells you if you have the right type, or it returns nullptr.  So you can do:

```
if (b *p = dynamic_cast<b *>(it->hasCurrent())) {
    // its b
} else if (c *p = dynamic_cast<c *>(it->hasCurrent())) {
    // its c
} else if (d *p = dynamic_cast<d *>(it->hasCurrent())) {
    // its d
} else {
    // none of the above
```

Of course, many OO purists will consider this a "bad code smell" -- you should define a virtual function in your interface class and call that, rather than testing for different derived types.

Comment: I was doing that but seemed so terrible that thought there was another way

Comment: @MarcosAyala that another way is to use polymorphism. Either via `std::function`, virtual dispatch or even function pointers.